# LibraryLink: How to read from a Mathematica stream in C?

Tags: librarylink, streams

Mathematica has a flexible streams interface. Functions like `Read` can read from a "stream" that may be backed by a file, pipe, string, network resource, etc. We can even [create our own custom streams](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefineInputStreamMethod.html).

**I am looking to implement an importer for a certain file format in C. How can I make it work with arbitrary Mathematica streams?**

More generally, how can I create a C++ `iostreams`-interoperable interface that reads from / writes to Mathematica streams?

---

LibraryLink has a `WolframStreamsLibrary.h` header, as well as some related functions in `WolframLibrary.h`.  What is the purpose of these?  Can I use them to read from arbitrary streams, or are they designed to implement new Mathematica stream types in C?  My impression is that they're intended for the latter.

---

An alternative idea is to try to use Mathematica callbacks to fill the C++ input stream's buffer:

- Use either [library callback functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html#894022691) or [MathLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/LibraryStructure.html#55120353)
- Identify the stream by an integer, the second argument of `InputStream`, e.g. `Cases[Streams[], InputStream[_, 15]]`
- Use `ReadList[stream, Character, n]` to read `n` characters, and use them to fill the C++ input stream buffer. Unfortunately, this is very slow, but I am not sure how to read only up to a certain amount of data from a stream that may not have `BinaryFormat -> True` (otherwise `BinaryReadList` would work). (Related: [Why does ReadString complain about the stream not being opened in binary format?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169707/12))

A big problem with this approach is that it is only practical if the C program is the exclusive user of the stream, or if it will read it all the way to the end.  With this approach, the C code might read more data than it needs, and the stream might not be rewindable.

---

I am looking for advice on how to approach this problem, and feedback on the specific implementation ideas above.