# Why does ReadString complain about the stream not being opened in binary format?

Tags: import, streams

This works fine:

```
stream = OpenRead["ExampleData/strings"];

ReadString[stream, EndOfFile]
(* "Here is text. 
And more text.
" *)

Close[stream]
(* "ExampleData/strings" *)
```

But if I use `EndOfBuffer` instead of `EndOfFile`, Mathematica issues an error message (despite returning the expected result).

```
stream = OpenRead["ExampleData/strings"];

ReadString[stream, EndOfBuffer]

During evaluation of BinaryReadList::bfmt: The stream InputStream[Name: strings, Unique ID: 5] has been opened with BinaryFormat -> False and cannot be used with binary data.

(* "Here is text. 
And more text.
" *)

Close[stream]
(* "ExampleData/strings" *)
```

**Why does this happen?  Is this a bug?**  This error is normally shown when binary read functions (such as [`BinaryRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryRead.html)) are used on streams that have `BinaryFormat -> False`. But `ReadString` is not such a function. It is designed to read textual data, with newlines interpreted.

---

Why am I trying to use `EndOfBuffer`?  [I am looking for a solution for reading form Mathematica streams in C++ code.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169705/12) One piece of the puzzle is reading only a limited amount of data (that fits into memory) with good performance.  I thought that instead of trying to explicitly control the size of the data returned, perhaps I should read as much as Mathematica itself keeps in its buffer.  Then running out of memory shouldn't be a problem.